# Calling java function in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am having a java file named FaceDetection.java that has a function named FaceDetectionMain and that take two arguments .The java file dont have any main function.Now i call this java class file function in my jsp page like this :

```
FaceDetection.FaceDetectionMain(imagepath,imagename);
```

But am getting an exception as follow :

```
Apr 21, 2014 10:44:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SharedCrpto1] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 90 in the jsp file: /uploadwebcamimage.jsp
FaceDetection cannot be resolved
87:          fos.write(imageData);
88:          String imagepath=filesstore+"\\"+imagename+".png";
89:          
90:          Boolean flag=FaceDetection.FaceDetectionMain(imagepath,imagename);
91:         %>
92:     </body>
93: </html>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 90 in the jsp file: /uploadwebcamimage.jsp
FaceDetection cannot be resolved
87:          fos.write(imageData);
88:          String imagepath=filesstore+"\\"+imagename+".png";
89:          
90:          Boolean flag=FaceDetection.FaceDetectionMain(imagepath,imagename);
91:         %>
92:     </body>
93: </html>
```

Please help me remove this exception.
Full stackTrace for exception is :

```
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: It can't find `FaceDetection`, but maybe you understood that?

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ But why ?FaceDetection java file is present in my default package.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ what you mean?I didnt get you

Comment: Did you import it to the page? `<%@ page import="org.something.something.FaceDetection"%>`

Comment: @mawburn I didnt get any error related to it.As it is in my default package of netbeans project.So i think it resolved the problem of import itself

Comment: Your FaceDetection class may be in the default package, but the class that is generated by processing your .jsp file is _not_ in the default package. Put your class in a package then reference it explicitly with an import from your jsp as `your.package.FaceDetection` — also, calling Java from a jsp is generally discouraged — send your data to the server (ajax maybe) and process it there, then make the results available to the jsp (maybe as a json response)

Answer (score 4):

Using the default package isn't a good practice, and often causes problems such as the one you are having (you can't import the default package, so no need to try the page import directives)  Try putting your class in a package and import it, you should find that it works properly.